# Getting statusbar notifications using notificationManager.getActiveNotifications()

Tags: android

I am getting all status bar notification using `notificationManager.getActiveNotifications()` but it's only return app lock's notification. Whenever notification occurs in whats app or in any other app this function not giving me active notification of other app. Is there any problem related to App-lock's notification? Because it's always running. Or is `getActiveNotifications()` is only giving me notification of app which is only in foreground?

Here is my code to get status bar notifications:

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        ArrayList<String> nPakageNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            StatusBarNotification[] activeNotifications
                    = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
            for (StatusBarNotification sbn : activeNotifications) {
                nPakageNameList.add(sbn.getPackageName());
                Log.i("SPakagesInN>>>", sbn.getPackageName());
            }
        }
```

Its just returning AppLock's package name. Not giving whats app or any other apps notification's. Is there any other way to check apps notification in status bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NotificationListenerService instead of NotificationManager. You can handle notification on onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) method when notification posted. Also, you can get the active notification list via getActiveNotifications() method of this Service.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService

Comment: Yes bro! but my boss saying me to work without getting android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE from user like other apps!!

Comment: Problem is whenever notification occurs locked app will be in foreground and app lock will show dialog even if app is not opened!

Comment: Dude, please look into getActiveNotifications() method of NotificationManager. This method returns the notifications which created by your application. Do you know which apps use this method? Clean Master and a few notification blocker apps I checked out use NotificationListenerService.